# Write string as it is to a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, latex

In a matlab script, I'm generating a latex table. A part of that table for example looks likes this.

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{b1}}
&
2 & 3 & 10092 & 10763 & 103390 & 2797 & 2929 & 3008 & 5\% & 8\% \\
& 4 & 2 & 20184 & 10763 & 74508 & 1830 & 1970 & 2029 & 8\% & 11\% \\
```

This string is saved in variable `str`. Now when I try to write `str` to a file by using the following code.

```
f = fopen( 'report\results.tex', 'w' );
fprintf( f, str );
fclose(f);
```

I get the following warning.

```
Warning: Invalid escape sequence appears in format string. 
See help sprintf for valid escape sequences.
```

That is probably due to many backslash characters in my string, which is used as escape sequence. Now how can I print this string to a file as it is.

Comment: Did you try to use `fwrite(f, str);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape the backslashes and percent signs:

```
str = strrep(str,'\','\\');
str = strrep(str,'%','%%');
```

If it's just text your printing, this'll be fine.

Minimal working example:

```
str = '2 & 3 & 10092 & 10763 & 103390 & 2797 & 2929 & 3008 & 5\% & 8\% \\'
str = strrep(str,'\','\\');
str = strrep(str,'%','%%');
f=fopen('testing123.txt','w');
fprintf(f,str);
fclose(f);
```

and the file reads:

```
2 & 3 & 10092 & 10763 & 103390 & 2797 & 2929 & 3008 & 5\% & 8\% \\
```

OR as Ben A. suggests, use [fwrite](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/fwrite.html):

```
fwrite(f,str)
```

and I think

```
fprintf(f,'%s',str)
```

will also do the trick, and it's best to also include a newline:

```
fprintf(f,'%s\n',str)
```

Comment: This does not work in places where I have double backslashes (\\\).

Comment: It seems you also have to escape the percent characters, see update ^^